# Find/ascertain latest wordpress db from multiple database copies

Tags: database, backup

I have multiple WordPress (v3.92) cloned databases. I do not know which one is the newest. How to ascertain which copy/clone of the database is the latest just from the database copy only.

Comment: in the properties of a MySQL table, there is the last time it has been modified

Answer (score 0):

It depends, but you may have the `Generation Time` of the file in the SQL file header, like this:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.2.10
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Aug 08, 2016 at 10:50 AM
-- Server version: 5.5.38
-- PHP Version: 5.6.1
```